# how can i feed command to a process opened using subprocess.POPEN and retrive the o/p

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, popen

My requirement is that I need to start a sqlcmd process and then feed the sql statement to that process and retrieve the output generated in that scenario. Before you guys suggest me to use sql library to run sqlcmd let me tell you that I can't do that, I've a requirement to implement this using sqlcmd only.

here is my current code

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def ms_sql_session():
    IP = "xxxx"
    port = '1433'
    username = 'sa'
    password = 'abc'
    connString = 'sqlcmd -S tcp:%s,%s -dmaster -U%s -P%s ' %(IP, port, username, password)

    try:
        session = Popen(connString, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        str_cmd = '''select @@version;
        go
        '''
        session.stdin.write(str_cmd)
        stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
        print stdout
        print stderr
        str_cmd = '''select @@version;
        go
        '''
        session.stdin.write(str_cmd)
        #stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
        print stdout
        print stderr
        str_cmd = '''select @@version;
        go'''
        session.stdin.write(str_cmd)
        #stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
        print stdout
        print stderr
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        return False

ms_sql_session()
```

I'm trying to execute 3 statement and retrieve the o/p but i'm getting the exception at the second stdin.write operation

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86) 
    Dec 10 2010 10:56:29 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)


(1 rows affected)


I/O operation on closed file
```

this is the output of my code.

Comment: Seems your Popen is not staying open and you are trying to write to it after it is closed. I usually call the Popen with each command I am trying to execute. Also stdout stderr are not redefined after the first `.communicate()`

Comment: actually someone told me that it keep on updating itself. that is why i removed the communicate call.

Comment: `.communicate()` closes the pipe and waits for the child process to finish therefore it may be called at most once and there is no point to access `session.stdin` afterwards (it is already closed).

Comment: s/the pipe/the pipes/ i.e., stdin, stdout, stderr.

Comment: ok, so how can I feed the multiple sql command to the open sqlcmd process and retrieve all the o/p ?

Comment: @Hemant: Do you need to feed one command at a time or is it acceptable to  provide all commands at once? Is there a marker that can be used to find the end of an output for a single command? btw, use my name if you want me to be notified about your comment.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm not sure what you mean. the thing is that I wanted to retain the handler to session based on the user for sql. As I've lot of sql files that need to be run based on user, some of these files itself create user and then the other files in sequence do operation on the new user. It can be a single file or multiple file depending on scenario for that test case. I need to maintain the same session till the test_case is finished. At the end of the test case I kill all the session/sub process.

Comment: @Hemant: From your comment I understand that the full command list is not known upfront, new commands may be created based on the result of previous commands. It means that you can't use `.communicate()` to execute all command at once. Can the session be preserved across several `sqlcmd` subprocesses? If it can't then you need to figure out how to detect end of output for a single command. btw, don't put new info in a comment, [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19805559/edit) instead. So that others can easily see related info.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a system cmd for that? I would recommend to use an SQL library for that...

Comment: I've this as a constraint. Can you help me with this issue.